# WebSocket Request (xhr_send) getting stalled (Tomcat and Apache HTTP)

Tags: angularjs, spring, apache, tomcat, websocket

My application used sockjs & Application is running on Tomcat 8 and APACHE HTTP as front end web server. I have observed that xhr_send request getting stalled and so hangs the application. On Chrome developer console, received following error

[image]

when xhr_send request stalled I never received CONNECTED response.

I used following code to setup websocket

```
socket = new SockJS(applicationMainService.getUrl()+'/ws');
stompClient = Stomp.over(socket);
```

Also received following error in Tomcat logs

```
[org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler@1e7904b0]: org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=https://pods.jlrint.com:443/PODSWeb/ws/112/fvi5za3c/websocket; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: WebSocket handshake failure; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: HTTP upgrade is not supported by the AJP protocol
```

06:35:04.129 [ajp-nio-8009-exec-11] DEBUG o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet - Could not complete request
org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsException: Uncaught failure in SockJS request, uri=https://xyzabc.com:443/MyRoot/ws/112/fvi5za3c/websocket; nested exception is org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.SockJsTransportFailureException: WebSocket handshake failure; nested exception is java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: HTTP upgrade is not supported by the AJP protocol
        at org.springframework.web.socket.sockjs.support.SockJsHttpRequestHandler.handleRequest(SockJsHttpRequestHandler.java:91) ~[spring-websocket-4.0.2.RELEASE.jar:4.0.2.RELEASE]

Please help.

Comment: `HTTP upgrade is not supported by the AJP protocol` AJP connector doesn't support websockets. Use HttpConnector and mod_proxy_wstunnel

Comment: Yeah I read it and aware of this, but looking out detailed steps or guide to do the same ? We are using mod_jk for load balancing and SSL certificate for HTTPS.

Comment: Do you have cluster or just one tomcat and one apache as proxy?

Comment: Yeah in Prod environment we do have Cluster ( 2 nodes with Load Balancer)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/42578769/1516873 example for cluster and sticky sessions

Comment: @user1516873  I have made following changes in httpd.conf but still observed that my request is getting stalled. I'm doing it in QA Environment ( which does not have Load balancer)      

<VirtualHost *:443>
ServerName my.example.com:443
SSLEngine On

-- SSL Cerification configuration changehere

ProxyPass /ws http://my.example.com:8081/MyWeb/ws
ProxyPassReverse /ws http://my.example.com:8081/MyWeb/ws

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{HTTP:UPGRADE} WebSocket [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP:CONNECTION} Upgrade [NC]
RewriteRule .* ws://my.example.com:8081/MyWeb$1 [P,L]

</VirtualHost>

Comment: sorry, maybe something lost, asterisk i think. It is better to ask on Serverfault as different question with right formatting.

Comment: I'm still not able to solve this. Raised question in serverfault. Thanks